# apache spark - which one encounters less memory bottlenecks - reduceByKey or reduceByKeyLocally?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have looked at the API and found the following documentation for both-

```
def reduceByKey(partitioner: Partitioner, func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

which merges the values for each key using an associative reduce function. 
This will also perform the merging locally on each mapper before sending results to a reducer, similarly to a "combiner" in MapReduce.

```
def reduceByKeyLocally(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): Map[K, V]
```

which merges the values for each key using an associative reduce function, but return the results immediately to the master as a Map. 
This will also perform the merging locally on each mapper before sending results to a reducer, similarly to a "combiner" in MapReduce.

I don't see much difference between the two except that reduceByKeyLocally returns the results back to the master as a map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is profound.

With `reduceByKey`, the pairs are represented as an `RDD`, which means the data remain distributed among the cluster. This is necessary when you are operating at scale.

With `reduceByKeyLocally`, all the partitions come back to the master to be merged into a single `Map` on that single machine. Similar to the `collect` action, which brings everything back to the master as an `Array`, if you are operating at scale, all those data will overwhelm a single machine completely and defeat the purpose of using a distributed data abstraction.